# How to send push notification to specific users on desktop using laravel?

Tags: push-notification, laravel-8

I am using pushjs https://pushjs.org/ library for sending desktop notification now when i reload page i receive notification but i want to show desktop notification to specific users please help me how can i send desktop notification for specific users that thank u.

[image]

Notification

```
     public function store(Request $request)
        {

         $users = User::where('user_type',1)->where('status',1)->pluck('id');
        foreach($users  as $value){
           $userNotification                   = new UserNotification();
           $userNotification->user_id          = $value;
           $userNotification->notification_id  = $notification->id;
           $userNotification->save();

           $usersEmail = User::where('user_type',1)->where('id',$value)->pluck('email');
           $details =[
                        'email' => $usersEmail
                    ];

         $emailJob = (new UserNotificationMailJob($details))->delay(Carbon::now()- 
         >addMinutes(1));
         dispatch($emailJob);

      }
       Session::flash('message','Notification is SuccessFully Sent');

      return  redirect()->back();
        }
```

**javascript**

```
    Push.create('Work From Here',{
        body:"You have new Notification!",
        timeout:5000,
        icon: iconPath
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- do you store notifications using pusher?
2- if you store the notifications in a database you must define the user who sends and the one who receives
3- could you contact me to help you because I need to know how you also implemented desktop notifications

Example:

```
$user = User::find($request->to_user_id);
      $user->notify(new InstalacionNotification($Instalacion));
```